# How to check permission change from the settings when app is open?

Tags: android, android-permissions

In android permission check I am checking for camera permission in **onResume()** but when -

1. User allow the permission
2. App is using the camera
3. User don't close the app and go to settings screen from notification panel
4. Disable the camera permission of that app

   When user comes back app is not asking for camera permission.

Comment: Can you share you code for asking permission for camera

Comment: So... Have you checked if user has permission in `onResume()` ?

Comment: Yes onResume not getting called

Answer (score 0):

After searching a lot found the answer -

> There is no call back if you change the permission when app is running (Settings -> App -> Permission -> Turn off the permission)

But it will call onCreate method again. So you need to check the permission in the **onCreate()**